# Tangent of an injective regular curve independent of its parametrization

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, curves

I am trying to show that the tangent of a regular curve is independent of its parametrization.

Let $c, \tilde c: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ be injective $C^1$-curves and $c'(t) \not=0, \tilde c'(s) \not= 0$. Now assume that $c$ and $c'$ define the same curve as point set, i.e. $c(\mathbb R)=\tilde c (\mathbb R)$. I want to show that $c'(t_0)$ and $\tilde c'(s_0)$ differ just by a $\mathbb R$-multiple, whenever $c(t_0)=c(s_0)$. We may assume $t_0=s_0=0,c(s_0)=t(s_0)=0$.

- I tried to parametrize by arc length, but how can I know that then the parametrizations must be the same up to orientation?
- I tried to look at the parameter change between $c$ and $\tilde c$, but how can I know that $\tilde c ^{-1} \circ c$ is differentiable?

Comment: Why can you assume that $c$ is injective? The regular curve $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ isn't injective on $[0, 2\pi]$. Is this just an extra assumption that you omitted from the title?

Comment: Yes, I am just interested in injective curves. Of course, if you have a "real intersection point", like in a set like $\infty$, in your curve, the direction of the tangent is not uniquely determined anymore.

Comment: I understand by regularity, that $c'(t) \not= 0$, not that the curves are parametrized by arc length. Just from $c'(t) \not=0$, I guess there is no hope that the tangents will be equal? This is not a problem from a text book or university. Just something that crossed my way by working out some definitions.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. I think everything is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c: I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose $|c'(t)| \not = 0$ for all $t \in I$. Suppose now that $\gamma: J \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is just a reparametrization of $c$ i.e there exists diffeomorphism $g: J \to I$ such that $c \circ g = \gamma$. By the chain-rule we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \gamma = \frac{d}{dt} (c \circ g) =\nabla c\Bigr|_{g(t)} \cdot g'(t)$$

Suppose $c(t_0) = \gamma(s_0) = (c \circ g)(s_0)$. If we take the above evaluation at $t = s_0$ then we have that $\gamma'(s_0) = \nabla c(g(s_0)) \cdot g'(s_0)$. If you can suppose as well that $c$ is injective, then:

$$c(t_0) = c(g(s_0)) \Rightarrow t_0 = g(s_0) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t = s_0} \gamma=\nabla c(t_0) \cdot g'(t_0)$$

The place where I see regularity helping is when we consider $c'(t_0)$. As it stands, we have no alternate form for $c'(t)$. If we can assume $|c'(t)| \not  = 0$ then we can parametrize by arc-length parameter $t = h(s)$. Then we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt} c(t) = \frac{d}{ds} c(h(s)) = \nabla c(h(s)) \cdot h'(s) = \nabla c(t) \cdot \frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{\nabla c(t)}{\frac{ds}{dt}} = \nabla c(t) \cdot \frac{1}{\|c'(t)\|} = \nabla c(t)$$

i.e the two become multiples once we take the above evaluation at $t = t_0$ since $g'(t_0) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: My problem was that I did not have a reparametrization $g$ between $c$ and $\tilde c$. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can describe the reparametrization explicitly by parametrizing by arc length. Let $s_c(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \lvert c'(u) \rvert du$ and $s_\tilde{c}(t) = \int_{s_0}^t \lvert \tilde{c}'(u) \rvert du$. Then $s_c$ and $s_\tilde{c}$ are both differentiable and injective, and so have differentiable inverses. Moreover, their derivatives are non-zero everywhere, which therefore also holds true for the differentiable map $h = s_\tilde{c}^{-1} \circ s_c$.

Now, note that $c \circ s_c^{-1} (0) = c(t_0)$ and $\tilde{c} \circ s_\tilde{c}^{-1}(0) = \tilde{c}(s_0)$ and $\lvert (c \circ s_c^{-1})'(t) \rvert = \lvert (\tilde{c} \circ s_\tilde{c}^{-1})'(t) \rvert = 1$ for all $t$, so it follows that (up to an overall change of orientation at least) $c \circ s_c^{-1} = \tilde{c} \circ s_{\tilde{c}}^{-1}$, or in other words, $c = \tilde{c} \circ h$. At this point, the claim follows from the chain rule, since

$$c'(t_0) = \tilde{c}'(h(t_0))h'(t_0) = \tilde{c}'(s_0)h'(t_0).$$

Comment: I see that you are way more comfortable with the subject that I am. Is it passible for you to parse through what I wrote below and let me know if what I did was correct?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: The first three lines look good to me, but I would say that you are done at that point? It's perhaps a bit confusing that you use $\frac{d}{dt}$ for one curve and $\nabla|$ for the other.

Comment: From $c'(t) \not=0$ I know that without of loss of generality $c_1'(t_0) \not= 0$. Hence locally $c_1^{-1}$ exists and a reparametrization is given by $\phi = c_1^{-1} \circ \tilde c_1$. How can I know that $\phi'(s_0)= \tilde c_1'(s_0) \cdot (c_1^{-1})'(t_0) \not= 0$? The second factor is not $0$ due to the inverse function theorem, but how can I be sure that $\tilde c_1'(s_0)\not=0$?

Comment: @M.Berger I'm not sure what you mean by $c_1$ (and how it differs from $c$), but if it's one of the curves you start out with, then it follows from regularity.

Comment: @fuglede in any multivariable calculus course this is how the express the derivative a composition where $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $c: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$. We can $ f \circ c: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and: $$\frac{d}{dt} (f \circ c) = \nabla f_{c(t)} \cdot c'(t)$$ i.e the composition is of one variable so the Leibniz notation is appropriate.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: All I was saying was that since both $\gamma$ and $c$ are maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, it would be natural to use the same notation for the derivatives in both cases. Other than that, the notation is of course fine, and I often find it easier to just stick to Jacobians throughout.

Comment: @M.Berger: You should be a bit careful about writing $(c_1^{-1})'$ since $c_1$ is probably defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which just happens to be one-dimensional).

Comment: @fruglede Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to illustrate exactly how the reparametrization works.

Comment: @fuglede By $c_1$ I mean the first component of $c$.

Comment: Ah, I see; then you can not ensure that $c_1'$ does not vanish (consider for instance Faraad's example of a circle).

Comment: @fuglede Thank you very much for giving more details. I tried to do the same, to paramatrize the curves by arc length. Can you explain me (probably it is an easy argument), how you conclude that two curves $d,\tilde d$, with $d(0)= \tilde d(0)$ and $|d′(t)|=|\tilde d'(1)|=1$ and $Im(d)=Im(\tilde d)$ must be equal (if we apply an change of orientation if necessary)?

Comment: Let $t > 0$ and consider the part of of the arc between $d(0)$ and $d(t)$. Then, since arc length is invariant under reparametrization, we can use either $d$ or $\tilde{d}$ to calculate the arc length. If we use $d$, we find that the length is $\int_0^t \lvert d'(u) \rvert du = t$. At the same time, this arc is also the arc from $\tilde{d}(0)$ to $\tilde{d}(s)$ for some $s$, so by calculating its length using $\tilde{d}$ we must necessarily have $s = ± t$.

Comment: So, all I'm really saying there is that the line integral is well-defined. The details would involve defining the arc length from $d(0)$ to $d(t)$ as a Riemann sum in a way that does not use any of the curves (and thus give the same result for both of them)..

Comment: Okay, so that is the part I am actually interested in. We need that arc length is a property that can be fully regained from the point set of a $C^1$-curve. Can you give me any reference where I can find where this is done?

Comment: The cheap answer is that the arc length is defined by a curve integral, so one thing you could do is search for "curve integral invariance reparametrization" or something to that extent. The arc length is a somewhat simple example though, and the way I was first introduced to it, it was actually *defined* geometrically: You approximate the arc length by splitting the path in *n* linear pieces, calculating the sum of the lengths of those. For finer and finer subdivisions of the arc, this (parametrization independent) sum will tend to the Riemann integral of $\lvert c' \rvert$.

Comment: Actually, it looks like that definition is on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Definition_for_a_smooth_curve

Comment: How is about using the constant rank theorem for $C^1$-maps on our curve $c: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$? It will give us a diffeomorphism $\Phi$, s.t. $\Phi \circ c$ just takes values on the $x$-axes. Hence $\Phi \circ \tilde c$ does the same. So there is no chance for the tangents to be not multiples of each other and applying $\Phi^{-1}$ gives us the result for the original tangent vectors? But probably a much too strong theorem for an elementary assertion.